# How to get column names from a dataframe dynamically to geojson properties

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, geojson, azure-databricks

I am trying to read the column names from dataframe and append it to the geojson properties dynamically it worked by hard coding the column names but i want those not by hard coding
can any one help me how to get those values (not by geojson iterating rows)

```
import pandas as pd
import geojson

def data2geojson(df):
    #s="name=X[0],description=X[1],LAT-x[2]"
    features = []
    insert_features = lambda X: features.append(
            geojson.Feature(geometry=geojson.Point((float(X["LONG"]),float(X["LAT"]))),
                            properties=dict(name=X[0],description=X[1])))
    df.apply(insert_features,axis=1)
    #with open('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/geojson11.geojson', 'w', encoding='utf8') as fp:
     #   geojson.dump(geojson.FeatureCollection(features), fp, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False)
    print(features)

df=spark.sql("select * from geojson1")
df=df.toPandas()
data2geojson(df)
```

Comment: Hi, it's just `df.columns`.

Comment: @Jottbe thanks a lot for your reply I am able to fetch the columns with df.columns but unable to pass it into the "properties=dict(s)" 
Could you please help me

Comment: In case you have a list of column descriptions the same length as the number of columns, you can do `dict(zip(df.columns, descriptions)))`, if you don't have them, you can do something like `{col: 'n/a' for col in df.columns}`.

Comment: @Jottbe awesome Thanks a ton this worked for me {col: 'n/a' for col in df.columns}
Thanks a lot again